# Rewrite a function using map

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

How can this function be implemented with map function? I solved it with lambda, but can't do with map...

```
def general_poly(L):
    """ L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
    Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value
    n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 """
    return lambda x: sum ([n * x ** (len (L) - i - 1) for i, n in enumerate (L)])
```

Comment: A map *maps* a list, not a single value. You probably want to use `map` in the `sum`...

Comment: Right, I know that map is applied to list, I do not know yet how to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `map` maps an iterable of values `x1,x2,...,` with a function `f` to an iterable of values `f(x1),f(x2),...`. So in this case you cannot convert the lambda expression into a map expression.

You can however use `map` to generate the values you feed to the list, furthermore you can define a function into a function. Like:

```
def general_poly(L):
    """ L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
    Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value
    n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 """
    def f(x):
        return sum(map(lambda y:y[1]*x**(len(L)-y[0]),enumerate(L,1)))
    return f
```